# Одна оконная процедура для нескольких окон

Tags: c++, winapi

Можно ли использовать оконную процедуру для дочернего и родительского окна одновременно?
Например:

```
wc.lpfnWndProc = Main::_WndProc;
hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_CLIPCHILDREN,
        wc.lpszClassName,
        L"MainWindow",
        WS_POPUP | WS_MINIMIZEBOX,
        //WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        windowX, windowY, windowWidth, windowHeight,
        nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

childhWnd = CreateWindowEx(0,
        wc.lpszClassName,          
        nullptr,
        WS_CHILD,
        //WS_SYSMENU,
        30, 40, windowWidth, windowHeight,
        hWnd, nullptr, hInstance, (PVOID)nullptr);
```

Paint:

```
WM_PAINT:
{
     Paint(hWnd);
     Paint2(childhWnd);
}
```

Будет нарисовано на родительской форме одно, а чуть ниже на дочерней - другое

Comment: Попробуйте - и узнаете. Что мешает проверить экспериментально?

Comment: Только так обрабатывать сообщение WM_PAINT не следует. Оно посылается конкретному окну для отрисовки только этого окна. Хендл окна передаётся оконной процедуре в качестве параметра, его и нужно использовать.